# ReactJS onClick on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

I'm having major issues with getting onClick to work on my mobile site. It works perfectly well on my Desktop website and when I test on mobile devices. However, when I try and test on an iPhone, the function never triggers - I even put in a console.log() and used the Safari Debugging tool to check. I've tried adding `cursor:'pointer';` to my CSS for the element, but to no avail.

This is my JSX: 
`<img src={require("./images/lineMenu.png")} className="lineMenu" onClick={() => this.onSetSidebarOpen(!this.state.sidebarOpen)} />`

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Edit:
The repository that the project is on is:
https://github.com/raghavmecheri/BinIt_Website 
The file being referenced is Navbar.js

Comment: If you change `onClick` to `onTouchEnd` does it work?

Comment: @DanielBank Unfortunately, no